# waf - cross compile, compiler detection

Tags: compilation, cross-compiling, waf

I got a cross compiled rootfs in `${ARMHOST}` which I previously created via `buildroot` for a `armv5te`/`ARM9` (`ARM926t` core also known as `ARM926ej-s`) target trying to use the CodeLite toolchain

```
waf distclean
ARMHOST="${HOME}/buildroot-2013.08/output/host";
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${ARMHOST}/usr/lib/pkgconffg/";
export CC="${ARMHOST}/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/gcc";
export AR="${ARMHOST}/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ar";
export CROSS_COMPILE="/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-";
export CFLAGS="-march=armv5te -I${ARMHOST}/usr/include/ -I${ARMHOST}/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/";
export LDFLAGS="-L${ARMHOST}/usr/lib/";
waf configure debug
```

Resulting in

```
'distclean' finished successfully (0.000s)
Setting top to                           : ~/Desktop/myapp 
Setting out to                           : ~/Desktop/myapp/build 
Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : not found 
Checking for 'icc' (c compiler)          : not found 
could not configure a c compiler!
(complete log in ~/Desktop/myapp/build/config.log)
```

The wscript uses `context.load('compiler_c gnu_dirs glib2')` in each stage to load features.

---

**Update #1** - if I replace `compiler_c` by `gcc` then I endup with:
CC="${ARMHOST}/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gneabi/bin/gcc" AR="${ARMHOST}/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ar" ./waf configure
Setting top to                           : ~/myapp
Setting out to                           : ~/myapp/build 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : ${ARMHOST}/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/gcc
Could not determine the compiler type

---

**So how can I tell waf that this compiler is gcc based? (code sourcery lite 2013 toolchain)**

Do I have to create a new compiler profile or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use .../host/opt/ext-toolchain/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/gcc but `.../host/opt/ext-toolchain/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` - gcc detection is obviously done by some voodoo